# DateTime volume 9000+

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm sure this has already been answered but no matter what i type relating to date time i get a different answer completely unrelated to what i need so bear with me ^_^

If i have a Date Time literal

```
dim IDate as DateTime = #6:21:00am#
```

and i create a date based on a day

```
dim iCurrentDate as DateTime = (2012,9,9,6,0,0)
```

now i already know that iCurrentDate is **Greater** than iDate because of the Date
,
How can i compare the **times** of these days?

For example, i want this to return that iDate is **Greater** than iCurrentDate because 6:21am is > 6:00 am

edit: I'm actually using c# i dunno why i wrote this question in vb.net , also it has a seconds component.

Comment: What does your title mean? (And as to actually using C#: you don't have Date literals in C# AFAIK :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeSpan structure is here for you

```
Dim t1 as New TimeSpan(IDate.Hour, IDate.Minute, IDate.Seconds)
Dim t2 as New TimeSpan(ICurrentDate.Hour, ICurrentDate.Minute, ICurrentDate.Seconds)

if t2 > t1 then
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Test the `Hour` and `Minute` components individually

```
If IDate.Hour > iCurrentDate.Hour Then
  Return True
ElseIf IDate.Hour = iCurrentDate.Hour And IDate.Minute > iCurrentDate.Minute Then
  Return True
End If

Return False
```

Comment: Uhm... but if `IDate.Hour<iCurrentDate.Hour` and `IDate.Minute > iCurrentDate.Minute` your code returns true... am I wrong?

Comment: @Marco - Correct. Good catch.

Comment: Now remains only to test seconds

Comment: @Steve - If you assume that's needed. From the example given, `IDate` does not have a seconds component.

Comment: This is a good solution but i believe Steve's is better, simply because it factors seconds and i can include it in my if statement that already exists, i can't add an else if into it. I didn't state this in the question i guess, so i will still vote your answer up

Comment: ohhh right, the literal doesn't have a seconds component in my example either, it does in my code tho ^_^ sorry

Answer (score 2):

Just use the TimeOfDay property:

```
Sub Main

    Dim date1 As DateTime = #6:21:00am#
    Dim date2 as New DateTime(2012,9,9,6,0,0)

    Console.WriteLine("date1 > date2: {0}", (date1 > date2))
    Console.WriteLine("date1.TimeOfDay > date2.TimeOfDay: {0}", (date1.TimeOfDay > date2.TimeOfDay))

End Sub

'Result:
'date1 > date2: False
'date1.TimeOfDay > date2.TimeOfDay: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the value of `DateTime` by converting it to minutes using the `.TotalMinutes`

```
if iCurrentDate.TotalMinutes > IDate.TotalMinutes Then
'iCurrectdate is greater
else
'IDate is greater
End If
```

Comment: In which version of framework, DateTime has a member called TotalMinutes?

Comment: You are talking about TimeSpan, which you need to use with the .Subtract of the DateTime. Probably not good if one of the variables does not have the day part.